# Why can not hashing key android for facebook

Tags: android, facebook

I use `nativescript` on coding and log in pass on debug mode but `hashing` form `openssl` and log in facebook cannot log in because not key hash and show warning like this.
How to fix it?

```
keytool.exe -exportcert -alias [alias-name] -keystore [keystore-path] | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
Enter keystore password:

'Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore [keystore-path] -destkeystore [keystore-path] -deststoretype pkcs12"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create apk you want and generate key with
`keytool -list -printcert -jarfile yourapkname.apk`
after that select key and paste in
http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php
to generate base64